# Program that takes a screenshot of the screen if it sees a certain color/colors and send it thru a discord bot or webhook?

Tags: python, discord, screenshot, pyautogui

Question: How can I make my bot take a screenshot of the screen if it sees a certain color/colors and send it thru a discord bot or webhook? I'm right now developing a program where it detects if something has died in a game or if someone has been killed. I'm using `pyautogui` to tell the program where to look if something does happen in the game. But if something does happen i would want it to detect a certain color/colors and take a screenshot and send it to a discord channel.

This is my code:

```
from pyautogui import * 
import pyautogui 
import time 
import keyboard 
import random
import win32api, win32con

while 1:
    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('tribelog.png', grayscale=False, confidence=0.8)  != None:
        print("Tribelog Located")
        time.sleep(0.5)
    else:
        print("Tribelog Not Located")
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

Any help would be appreciated as I'm new to programming.

Comment: To take a screenshot: https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html

Comment: I don't know that `pyautogui` gives you such color detection. Can you take different versions of `tribelog.png` with the different colors you want, and reuse `locationOnScreen()`?

Comment: To upload an image to Discord: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-upload-an-image